# 404 Page not found error when I try to access Custom module in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, custom

I have created 2 custom module inside vendor folder .This is my layout structure :

```
-app
  -code
    -Company
      -Blog
      -HelloWorld
        -Controller
          -Hello
            -World.php
        -registration.php
        -etc
          -module.xml
          -frontend
            -routes.xml
```

Both are enabled .

This is my code for `routes.xml` for HelloWorld module :

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
  <router id="standard">
    <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
        <module name="Company_HelloWorld"/>
    </route>
 </router>
</config>
```

This is my code in `module.xml` :

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_HelloWorld" setup_version="1.0.0">
   </module>
   </config>
```

This is my registration.php file :

```
<?php 
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Company_HelloWorld',
    __DIR__
);
```

This is my controller code :

```
 <?php
 namespace Company\HelloWorld\Controller\Hello;


 class World extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
 {
   public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context)
  {
      return parent::__construct($context);
  }

  public function execute()
  {
    echo 'Hello World';
    exit;
  } 
}
```

This is my layout code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>

</body>
</page>
```

& Same for another module. I have already executed `setup:upgrade` command but still, I am getting 404 error when I try to access any one these modules.

Comment: can you show your layout file and tree folder structure of your module

Comment: I have updated my question.Currently I have given exit; in execute() method of controller but it does not even come in controller I guess.

Comment: In magento2 You can create module Inside `app/code` folder

Comment: I have created inside app/code only .

Comment: i can't perfectly understand your layout structure.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check it.

Answer (score 5):

Try this `module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Company_HelloWorld" setup_version="1.0.0" active="true">
```

Comment: still the same error.

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: try to change `setup_version="1.0.0"`  to  `setup_version="2.0.1"`

Answer (score 5):

I have attach one Demo Tutorial for you.

Here is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7-ErEahwIPYc0xEOVh3eWV1ejA/view?usp=sharing

Put it inside your `app/code` folder.
please check it. hope this will help you.

Comment: After add `_isAllowed` function on Controller url works  `protected function _isAllowed() {  return true;    }`

Answer (score 1):

you have no created any controller so it will not find any url so it will give you 404 error

Create **Controller** folder

Create **Index** folder inside Controller folder

Create **Index.php** file inside Index folder add below code in it.

```
<?php

namespace  Company\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
     public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Index action
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "helloworld";exit;
    }   



}
```

Now you can check url `helloworld/index/index`

Comment: Ofcourse I have created controller .I just didn't paste it's code in question

Comment: I have added controller code in my question.

Comment: Which url are you trying?

Comment: Now it comes to execute()  method of controller but displays only blank page.http://localhost/magento-demo/helloworld/hello/world

Comment: It worked after I executed cache flush command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change code in 2 files,

**app/code/Company/HelloWorld/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
  <router id="standard">
    <route id="company_helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
        <module name="Company_HelloWorld"/>
    </route>
 </router>
</config>
```

**app/code/Company/HelloWorld/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_HelloWorld" setup_version="2.1.1">
   </module>
   </config>
```

I have just made this two changes run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** and its working fine.

**localhost/magento-demo/index.php/helloworld/hello/world/**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I executed bin\magento cache:flush & It worked apparently.It was a cache issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to Deploy the content and upgrade the setup

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy